# web.whatsapp not delivering messages of robot

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I created a robot to send messages via web.whatsapp. The robot open the browser, open chat with contact, write the message, but the message is not delivered

im using python 2, selenium and chrome.webdriver

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import socket

message_text='Ola essa é uma mensagem automatizada de Whats App escrita pelo computador e enviada em uma campanha massiva de marketing. Obrigado pela atenção' # message
no_of_message=3 # no. of time 
moblie_no_list=[xxxxxxxxx] # list of phone number 

def element_presence(by,xpath,time):
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath))
    WebDriverWait(driver, time).until(element_present)

def is_connected():
    try:
        # connect to the host -- tells us if the host is actually
        # reachable
        socket.create_connection(("www.google.com", 80))
        return True
    except :
        is_connected()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("http://web.whatsapp.com")
sleep(10) #wait time to scan the code in second

def send_whatsapp_msg(phone_no,text):
    driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone={}&source=&data=#".format(phone_no))
    try:
        driver.switch_to.alert().accept()
    except Exception as e:
        pass


    sleep(5)
    txt_box=driver.find_element(By.XPATH , '//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]')
    txt_box.click()
    txt_box.send_keys("oi")
    sleep(2)
    txt_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)


for moblie_no in moblie_no_list:
    try:
        send_whatsapp_msg(moblie_no,message_text)

    except Exception as e:
        sleep(10)
        is_connected()
```

!https://ibb.co/7XWQxvr

Comment: If you are able to send the message and they are not being delivered, that should be whatsapp server issue, nothing to do with your robot.

Comment: when i send the message manually, whatsapp send the message normally